# Changing src of <a-box> with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am always able to change the src of a img element by addressing it's ID. First I define the element with the id "lol".

```
<img id="lol" src="" />
```

I then click a button that activates this function, which changes the src:

```
<script> document.getElementById('lol').setAttribute('src', `data.value[0].thumbnailUrl); </script>`
```

Now while this WORKS PERFECTLY for an img tag, this does not work for my a-box element:

```
<a-box id="lol" src="flammer.png" position="-10 0.5 1" rotation="0 45 0" width="1" height="1" depth="1"></a-box>
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I believe adding `src=""`(custom attribute) technically makes your html invalid? Maybe you could try using `data-src=""`?

Comment: It works when it's hardcoded, I can have a src with an image in it then. I just cant change it JS DOM-wize.

Comment: I know, but it's technically invalid. Although you may use it hardcoded, if you put it in a HTML validator and it would say its invalid. Therefore in js, you are not able to change those attributes. If you want to define attributes, you should use the `data-xxx=""` attributes.

Comment: OK, I will check it out thanks. When changing it in the inspector however, I find that it only works with local images - which may be my problem, as I am using an URL. Also: seems to work in the answer he's given down there. However, not really with local links.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me after a bit of tweaking. Run it in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body >
<p>Open inspector and look at src parameter of a-box which will be boo.png</p> 
<a-box id="lol" src="flammer.png" position="-10 0.5 1" rotation="0 45 0" width="1" height="1" depth="1"></a-box>

</body>

<script>
var data = {value:[{thumbnailUrl:"boo.png"}, {thumbnailUrl:"blah.png"}]}

 alert('Before: Src or a-box=' + document.getElementById("lol").getAttribute("src"))
 document.getElementById("lol").setAttribute("src", data.value[0].thumbnailUrl); 
 alert('After: Src or a-box=' + document.getElementById("lol").getAttribute("src"))

 </script>

 </html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I just tried changing it in the inspector however, and I find that it only works with local images - which may be my problem, as I am using an URL.

Comment: I am trying to build rep - any chance you can give me an upvote? I know you answered yourself but there was some value in my answer?

Comment: I upvoted Vanquished Wombat answer because he showed me that my code really did work - and that the problem was elsewhere. However, unless I am mistaken, there is no new code in this answer. It does however exemplify how my code did what it set out to do. It is still unclear why it did not work to actually change the image source visibly. This is most likely due to 3D rendering. I managed to solve this by instead of changing the src of a box, instead I created the whole box in the DOM, and it all worked.

Comment: Thank you kindly @JoakimVindenes. Your final solution is a good pointer for future visitors to the question.

Comment: Make sure your image is CORSed.

Comment: Useful explanation of cross origin resource sharing (CORS) at this site https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/